# Is it possible to immutably update a MarkLogic server, without having or having minimal downtime, with mlcp?

Tags: marklogic, mlcp

I've changed the configuration of a server image. I've started up a server with the new configuration. I can port all the data from one server to another using the mlcp copy (see before for similar script). I believe I can't allow the data to be edited whilst the transaction is occurring. That is from the start of the copying, to when the new server is linked back in, I can't have the data edited on the old server. I can only have the data read once the copying starts to occur.

Is it possible for me to push updates with mlcp? Is it possible for me to allow editing to occur on the server, whilst the data is being transferred, and still have the data consistent?

```
# moves all data in databases from a server to another server
# usage: ./copy.sh someServer.com anotherServer.com 
from=$1
to=$2

# input security database first so that the users are added
mlcp.sh copy -mode local -input_host $from -input_port 8000 \
    -input_username admin -input_password password \
    -input_database Security \
    -output_database Security \
    -output_host $to -output_port 8000 -output_username admin \
    -output_password password

mlcp.sh copy -mode local -input_host $from -input_port 8000 \
    -input_username admin -input_password password \
    -input_database Documents \
    -output_database Documents \
    -output_host $to -output_port 8000 -output_username admin \
    -output_password password
```

Answer (score 3):

MLCP provides a `snapshot` flag to make sure the entire run gives consistent results:

```
-snapshot <true,false>               Whether to use a consistent
                                     timestamp to fetch data from the
                                     source database
```

Should work for both `export` and `copy`.

Regarding pushing updates: you can repeat MLCP `copy`, but it might be easier to work with a blackout period; a period in which you disallow updates in your system. You could enforce that by putting forests in read-only mode on the source side.

Alternatively, you could also consider database replication. Read more about this in this guide:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/database-replication

HTH!

Comment: I agree that what Jordan's asking for seems to be database replication